# inf's in outputs for selection ratios in adehabitaths package

Tags: r

My Manly Selection Ratio results using the adehabitaths package includes several Inf outputs. I understand that I can censor the indivudals causing the Inf's from the analyses, however, in some cases I am getting Inf for over half of the individuals.

```
  `library(adehabitatHS)

Broods<-FinalVegBroods
Broods$Hen.ID <- factor(Broods$Hen.ID)

used <- subset(Broods, Broods$use == 1)
used <- used[c(0,-3:-47,-49:-58)]
used <- xtabs(~used$Hen.ID + used$Moisturenew, used)

used <- as.data.frame.matrix(used[1:19, 1:6])
rand <- subset(Broods, Broods$use == 0)
rand <- rand[c(0,-3:-47,-49:-58)]
rand <- xtabs(~rand$Hen.ID + rand$Moisturenew, used)
rand <- as.data.frame.matrix(rand[1:19, 1:6])

##### PVT Code for VegRSF #

pvt.W <- widesIII(used,rand,avknown = FALSE, alpha = 0.1)
pvt.W 
par(mfrow=c(1,2)) 
plot(pvt.W)`
```

I'm wondering what these Inf results actually represent and how it may influence the data, but mostly what is causing them and how and if I can fix it??

I would be glad to supply more information if required.

`************** Manly's Selection ratios for design III ********

1. Test of habitat selection for each animal:

   `Khi2Lj df       pvalue
   STGR201512         Inf  2 0.0000000000
   STGR201513         Inf  0 0.0000000000
   STGR201514   5.3096114  1 0.0212080867
   STGR201515   0.0000000  0 1.0000000000
   STGR201556   5.5451774  0 0.0000000000
   STGR2016204        Inf  2 0.0000000000
   STGR2016205  2.4327906  2 0.2962962963
   STGR2016307  5.1325260  2 0.0768220955
   STGR2016309  4.5596652  2 0.1023013283
   STGR2016321  0.3047875  2 0.8586501034
   STGR2016322 11.5419295  1 0.0006804398
   STGR2016328  4.9671534  2 0.0834442357
   STGR2016330  0.1734535  2 0.9169276250
   STGR2016331  2.6234302  2 0.2693576848
   STGR2016333        Inf  3 0.0000000000
   STGR2016334 11.2346899  3 0.0105222081
   STGR2016340  4.3812635  3 0.2231289938
   STGR2016342        Inf  2 0.0000000000
   STGR2016343  7.4623299  1 0.0063003410`

Answer (score 0):

I have discovered that what I was attempting to do was impossible due to there being an insufficient  sample size. I only had one random sample for every used.